# Angular 1.5 - Custom directive to show Money Color

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm creating a directive in Angular 1.5.x to write the $Money amount in red or green, depending on if it's a loss or profit.

```
<div  financial-Color amount="model.Money"></div>
```

My custom directive looks like this so far, how do I write out the $Money amount in Currency with the color?

```
app.directive('financialColor', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {
            'amount': '='
        },

        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch('amount', function (condition) {
                if (attrs.amount<0) {
                    element.css('color', 'red');
                }
                if (attrs.amount > 0) {
                    element.css('color', 'green');
                };
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: what do you want?? model.Money to be in currency format??

Comment: Yes, The ending results should look like <div class="green">$55</div> bascially

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`$watch`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch) you can check the `newValue` parameter in the callback function.

To get your desired value, use the [`currency`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/currency) filter to get the amount into the format you need.

To set the value you can use AngularJS's [`jqLite`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element#angularjs-s-jqlite) html method on the `element` to set the value.

Heres a working example (the amount value changes after 5 seconds to demonstrate the negative amount):

```js
// app.js
(function() {

  'use strict';

  angular.module('app', []);

})();

// main.controller.js
(function() {

  'use strict';

  angular.module('app').controller('MainController', MainController);

  MainController.$inject = ['$timeout'];

  function MainController($timeout) {

    var vm = this;

    vm.amount = 100.05;

    $timeout(function() {

      vm.amount = -55.10;

    }, 5000);

  }

})();

// financial-color.filter.js
(function() {

  'use strict';

  angular.module('app').directive('financialColor', financialColor);

  financialColor.$inject = ['$filter'];

  function financialColor($filter) {

    return {
      restrict: 'EA',
      scope: {
        'amount': '='
      },
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

        scope.$watch('amount', function(newValue, oldValue) {

          // set the value using the currency filter
          element.html($filter('currency')(newValue, '$', 2));

          if (newValue < 0) {

            element.css('color', 'red');

          } else if (newValue > 0) {

            element.css('color', 'green');

          }

        });
      }
    }
  }

})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainController as MainCtrl">

  <div financial-color amount="MainCtrl.amount"></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Implementation using ng-class

Directive:

```
app.directive('financialColor', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {
            'amount': '='
        },
        template: "<span ng-class=\"{'red':amount<0, 'green': amount>0}\">${{amount}}</span>"
    }
});
```

CSS

```
.red {color: red}
.green {color: green}
```